# How to solve a function between a range (0,2) with different steps for x and y in Fortran without arrays?

Tags: function, fortran

Basically, I need to solve a function, ill use `x^2 * y^3` for an example, but using the `x` and `y` values over a range of `(0,2)`, with different steps for `x` values and for `y` values. For example, if the step was 1 for both `x` and `y`, I would just solve the function for `(0,0),(0,2),(2,0), and (2,2)`.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this in Fortran without using arrays. I was thinking about using a "DO" and then solving the function for all of the initial `"y"` values, while using the correct amount of steps for `"x,"` but im not sure how I would get the second `"y"` value with the `"x"` values reset so that the `"y"` can be calculated with all of the `x` values.

Thank you!

Comment: You can have a do construct like `do x = 0, 2` and nest another do construct inside it, like `do y = 0, 2`, and the iterator will cover all combinations of x and y in the range.

Comment: I understand your question as "I need to *compute* the value of a function that takes two arguments, x and y", is it correct? The solution to your problem depends entirely on how you will use the resulting values (output to a file, store in an array, estimate an average value or a sum, etc.). Please update the question with this information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution, based on `do concurrent` construct in modern Fortran (>2008) which is guaranteed to be equally or more efficient than the conventional do-loops in Fortran:

```
program hello
    integer :: x,y
    real    :: stepSizeX = 0.1, stepSizeY = 0.2
    do concurrent(x=0:2:1,y=0:2:1)
        write(*,*) (stepSizeX*x)**2 * (stepSizey*y)**3
    end do
end program Hello
```

You can test it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_fortran_online.php) (set the compiler's Fortran standard to -std=f2008 or -std=gnu).

Comment: I'm curious where the efficiency guarantee comes from - I can't think of anywhere that the standard says such thing. Can you give me a pointer?

Comment: Not in this particular case though. I should have mentioned it.